# What is the recommended way to install glibc 2.27 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, glibc, backport

I tried the following command, but it seems that the package was not found.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libc-bin=2.27-3ubuntu1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.27-3ubuntu1' for 'libc-bin' was not found
```